# Positional ordering with minimal modification

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Let's say I have a list of items stored in a database, and I want to keep a user-modifiable positional ordering based on a single field. For instance, if I have five items ABCDE, I want to move D to before B by only:

1. Knowing the existing "positioning" values of ABCDE
2. Changing only the positioning value of D

The most straightforward way I can think of to solve the problem is simply to use float values for positioning and, when moving an item, make its new positional value halfway between its new neighbors. That seems like it'll end up messy across large numbers of moves over time, and I'm wondering if there's a better or more interesting approach. Thoughts?

Comment: You can have a renumbering pass once things become messy (consecutive differences get dangerously close to your floats' precision). In the worst case though (e.g., constantly moving far elements to second place), it will mean renumbering once in the number of floats' mantissa bits (23 for float, 52 for double, etc.).